# Index the data by date in R

Tags: r, date, indexing, dataframe

I'm trying to index my data frame. There is a column of "Date" in my data (from "01/05/2015" to "31/05/2015"), and I want to create another column(1 to 31) which indicates the distinguished date. For example:

```
                Date          Indicator 
                01/05/2015     1
                01/05/2015     1
                02/05/2015     2
                11/05/2015     3
                11/05/2015     3
```

How can I solve it easily?

Actually, I have another worry, if I have a column "ID" before the "Date", and I only want to create the indicators for each ID, like this:

```
ID    Date          Indicator
ID1 1992-02-27         1
ID1 1992-02-27         1
ID1 1992-01-14         2
ID1 1992-02-28         3
ID2 1992-02-01         1
ID2 1992-02-01         1
ID2 1992-02-01         1
ID2 1992-07-01         2
```

How to resolve it? I have to use a for-loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more accurate as to which technology you're using. SQL?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I'm using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
dates <- c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92", "02/01/92", "02/01/92")
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y"))
df$Indicator <- c(1,1+cumsum(diff(df$Date)!=0))
```

Result:

```
> df
        Date Indicator
1 1992-02-27         1
2 1992-02-27         1
3 1992-01-14         2
4 1992-02-28         3
5 1992-02-01         4
6 1992-02-01         4
7 1992-02-01         4
```

EDIT:

```
dates <- c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92", "02/01/92", "02/01/92")
ID <- c(rep("ID1",3), rep("ID2",4))
df <- data.frame(ID = ID, Date = as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y"))


my_index <- function(date) { c(1,1+cumsum(diff(date)!=0)) }
df$Indices <- do.call(c,tapply(df$Date, df$ID, my_index))
```

Comment: What happens if want to to use posixct data type instead of Date?